# There are constantly overflows on the card structure

Tags: flutter, button, overflow, card

I just started flutter. I tried to make a card structure but I think it is quite wrong. I could never fix it. I am using Gridview extend. In this way, the column numbers change dynamically as the screen gets smaller or larger. but i keep getting overflow error what should i do.

```
 var response = sepet.itemsCount[item.name];
 return SizedBox(
   child: Padding(
     padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
     child: Column(
       crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
       children: [
         Card(
           shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
               borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0))),
           child: InkWell(
             customBorder: RoundedRectangleBorder(
               borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
             ),
             onTap: () {},
             child: Column(
               children: <Widget>[
                 ListTile(
                   title: Text(item.name ?? ''),
                   subtitle: Text(item.defaultPrice.toString() + '\$'),
                 ),
                 Padding(
                   padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                   child: Row(
                     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                     children: [
                       Row(
                         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                         children: <Widget>[
                           countChanger(sepet, false, item),
                           Padding(
                             padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
                             child: Text(
                               response != null ? response.toString() : '0',
                               style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                             ),
                           ),
                           countChanger(sepet, true, item),
                         ],
                       ),
                       ButtonTheme(
                         height: 25,
                         minWidth: 25,
                         child: ElevatedButton(
                           onPressed: () {
                             !isAdded
                                 ? sepet.sepeteEkle(item)
                                 : sepet.deleteItem(item);
                           },
                           style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                             primary: !isAdded
                                 ? Colors.teal
                                 : Colors.red,
                           ),
                           child: Text(!isAdded ? 'Ekle' : 'Çıkar'),
                         ),
                       ),
                     ],
                   ),
                 )
               ],
             ),
           ),
         ),
       ],
     ),
   ),
 );
```

[image]

[image]

My gridview extend structure is like this

```
child: GridView.extent(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        maxCrossAxisExtent: 250.0,
        crossAxisSpacing: 20.0,
        mainAxisSpacing: 20.0,
        children: List.generate(foods!.length, (index) {
          return itemCard(foods[index].menuItem ?? MenuItem(), value);
        }),
```

Comment: Try to add FittedBox around the first Row    
` Padding(
                   padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                   child:FittedBox(child: Row(
                     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                     children: [...]))`

Comment: FittedBox worked thank you

Answer (score 0):

The question you need to answer is what would you like to happen if the width of that card is so small? Do you want a different arrangement of those elements? If you do decide on what that would look like and check the constraint with `LayoutBuilder` Or the whole screen width with `MediaQuery` whatever you feel is best. You could also make that bit scroll horizontally by using `SingleChildScrollView`. This is a design decision. You must image what things look like when screen size changes, and be as deliberate as possible with the responsiveness rather then to just try to find some magic widget which we are all guilty of doing sometimes.

Answer (score -1):

Try below code hope its helpful to you I have try similar to your code and add your widgets in **Expanded** or **Flexible** Widgets.

[flexible widgets](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html)

[expanded Widgets](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html)

```
   GridView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      itemCount: 4,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
        return Container(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                child: Text('data'),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      height: 35.0,
                      width: 100.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          InkWell(
                            child: Icon(Icons.remove, color: Colors.green),
                            onTap: () {},
                          ),
                          Spacer(),
                          Text(
                            '0',
                            style: Theme.of(context)
                                .textTheme
                                .subtitle2!
                                .copyWith(fontSize: 16.0),
                          ),
                          Spacer(),
                          InkWell(
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.add,
                              color: Colors.green,
                            ),
                            onTap: () {},
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Text(
                        'Sub Total',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
       gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                  maxCrossAxisExtent: 170.0,
                  mainAxisExtent: 93,
                ),
    ),
```

Your Result screen like-> [image]

Comment: The structure here is unfortunately not responsive either. As the screen gets smaller, the number of columns does not change, and when I added these buttons, overflows occurred.

Comment: Ok you want to this `Grid Widgets` is depends on your screen size for all platforms?

Comment: yes it depends on the screen size

Comment: @beynelmilel check my updated answer and use `SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent()` widget for responsive `Grid Widgets`